# Azure Service Fabric inter service communication

Tags: c#, azure, queue, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I currently have one Service Fabric application that is composed of multiple Services. What I'm trying to achieve is a Queuing mechanism **so one Service can publish a message to a queue, and another Service can receive messages from the same queue**.

The following doesn't work (for the Listener service, there is nothing to dequeue):

`PublisherService`:

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var myQueue = await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableQueue<string>>("fooQueue");
    while (true)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        using (var tx = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
        {
            // Put some message in the queue
            await myQueue.EnqueueAsync(tx, "Foobar");

            await tx.CommitAsync();
        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

`ListenerService`:

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var myQueue = await StateManager.GetOrAddAsync<IReliableQueue<string>>("fooQueue");
    while (true)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        using (var tx = this.StateManager.CreateTransaction())
        {
            var result = await myQueue.TryDequeueAsync(tx);

            if (result.HasValue)
            {
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, "New message receieved: {0}", result.Value.ToString());
            }

            await tx.CommitAsync();
        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**It looks like the scope of a queue is limited to a single Service**. This doesn't appear to be a limitation specified in the documentation.

So my questions are:

- is this *actually* some undocumented limitation?
- or is there something wrong in the code above?
- how could I achieve the scenario above (one service adds messages to a queue, another service retrieves messages from the same queue)?

Obviously I could use an Azure Service Bus, but I can't for several reasons:

- in my actual real-world scenario, I will have several queues (variable number) so it would require creating Service Bus Queues on demand (which is not exactly a *fast* operation)
- adds a dependency to another Azure service (so increases the failure probability for the whole system)
- costs more
- more complex deployment
- etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReliableQueues are local to a service yes, because its intent is to store state for that particular service. That state is replicated to other instances. It is like a normal `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>` in .Net.

For a low cost solution maybe you can use [Azure Storage Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues). Yes, it adds a dependency but it has a high availability. It is a tradeoff that only you can decide to accept or not.

On the other hand, think out of the box:

Create a stateful service with multiple ReliableQueues and expose methods other services can call using stand remoting communication like:

```
class QueuingService
{
    void AddToQueue<T>(string queuename, T input) { .. }
    void DeQueue(string queuename) { .. }
}
```

This creates of course a dependency but it has all the safety mechanisms Service Fabric provides and does not cost you much. But then again, you are building a poor mans service bus/azure storage queue yourself.

About the docs, no it does not says so with many words that a reliable queue is tied to 1 service but it depends on how you interpret [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections)

> Service Fabric offers a stateful programming model available to .NET developers via Reliable Collections. Specifically, Service Fabric provides reliable dictionary and reliable queue classes. When you use these classes, **your state (my interpretation: The state of the service)** is partitioned (for scalability), replicated (for availability), and transacted within a partition (for ACID semantics).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this makes sense. I'm not sure yet which way I'm gonna choose (Azure Storage Queues or remoting communication). Each has its own pros/cons. Thanks again, that was very helpful.

Comment: But then again, you are building a poor mans service bus/azure storage queue yourself. - this means this is not proper way of using ReliableQueue?

Comment: @AsValeO what do you mean with "a proper way". There is, if you use it for what it is designed to use for: store data at the location it is used, that is inside a single stateful service. You just can't turn it into something else, like a queue that spans multiple services.

Comment: can we use anything like azure storage queues on premise? we need some type of event-driven/on premises solution, where a service will fire off a message, and it would be stored in a queue somehwere, where another service will pop it off the queue and process it

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Priority Queue Service](https://github.com/toddabel/PQService), which was created for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a fault-handling retry pattern to all of your calling code, you should not need a queue in between your calls, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication

Relevant part from the link is here:

> An exception handler is responsible for determining what action to take when an exception occurs. Exceptions are categorized into retryable and non retryable.
>   Non retryable exceptions simply get rethrown back to the caller.
>   retryable exceptions are further categorized into transient and non-transient.
>   Transient exceptions are those that can simply be retried without re-resolving the service endpoint address. These will include transient network problems or service error responses other than those that indicate the service endpoint address does not exist.
>   Non-transient exceptions are those that require the service endpoint address to be re-resolved. These include exceptions that indicate the service endpoint could not be reached, indicating the service has moved to a different node.